# Hi, im new at react native, i wanna know how to limit state value that will receive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have state key named temperatureHistory that must have only 6 array inside.

I already tried this code below and it didn't work:

```
this.setState ( { temperatureHistory : min(0, max(value, 6)) } );
```

Comment: Why you wanna to limit the state?

Comment: Are you trying to do `this.setState({ temperatureHistory: value.slice(0, 6) })`?

Comment: What you mean by it doesnt work? Does it throw an error/doesnt update anything on UI?

Comment: You will have to provide us with more information. From the code you're providing us it seems like you're calling a function called `min` with the arguments `0, max(value, 6)` to be assigned to your state's `temperatureHistory` key.

Answer (score 0):

in your particular case you are looking for an alternative to limit the size of an array in JavaScript, this is a concept that is not attached to react Native as you can set any value to your state.

In this case you can do:

```
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant', 'tiger', 'lion'];


this.setState({ animals: animals.slice(0, 6) })
```

You can read more about [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  and how you can move the start / end of the portion of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Are looking something like this? [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exercise-of-class-74u3w)

you can use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to limit for six values. like this.

```
state = {
    items: [2, 23, 2, 42, 232, 40, 90, 2342]
  };
```

JSX

```
  <ul>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
    <hr />
    {JSON.stringify(this.state.items)}
  </ul>
```

function

```
  handleClick = () => {
    let randomVal = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),0,1,10,110,Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),23]
    this.setState({
      items: randomVal.slice(0,6)
    });
  };
```